# How to add the channel in which the message was edited?

Tags: discord.py

I just want to add to the embed the channel in which the message was edited. So far no luck in finding a solution.

```py
@Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        if not after.author.bot:
            if before.content != after.content:
                embed = Embed(title="Message edit",
                              description=f"Edit by {after.author.display_name}.",
                              colour=after.author.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                fields = [("Before", before.content, False),
                          ("After", after.content, False)]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a message was edited, the channel is going to be the same as where the message was originally sent, use the `Message.channel` attribute to get the channel.

```py
@Cog.listener()
async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
    channel = before.channel # or after.channel
    await channel.sent('whatever')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked. I did `channel.mention` so it outputs exactly what i need.

Comment: No worries, remember to accept and upvote the answer if it helped

Comment: I don't have enough rep lol but posted the updated code for anyone that might need it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code for anyone that might need it.

```py
@Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before, after):
        if not after.author.bot:
            if before.content != after.content:
                channel = before.channel
                embed = Embed(title="Message edit",
                              description=f"Edit by {after.author.display_name}.",
                              colour=after.author.colour,
                              timestamp=datetime.utcnow())

                fields = [("Before", before.content, False),
                          ("After", after.content, False),
                          ("Channel", channel.mention, False),]

                for name, value, inline in fields:
                    embed.add_field(name=name, value=value, inline=inline)

                await self.log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```